# which of the following statement are true ..?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

This problem is from the test NBHM (National Board of Higher Mathematics)  for M.Sc scholarships, conducted in India.

For question 1.9, I chose only option b ) and for Question 1.10, I chose the option  b) and c).

For 1.9 I took A as an idempotent matrix and using that, I discarded option a) and c).

For 1.10, I have no idea how to proceed.

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: If $A$ is $2\times2$ singular, then its characteristic polynomial is $x^2-tx$ where $t$ is the trace of $A$.